# Determine the parameter value, so that the function would be a distribution function

Tags: probability

I have the following function

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x= \leq 1\\ 
x+c & \text{ if } x= 1<x<2\\ 
c+4-x & \text{ if } x=2\leq x<3 \\ 
0 & \text{ if } x= x\geq 3
\end{cases}$

and I need to determine the value of $c$, so that $f(x)$ would be a density function.

I need that $\int_\infty^\infty$ needs to be equal to $1$, since the domain of the function is $(\infty, \infty)$.

The integrals of the first and fourth branches are $0$. No need to calculate anything.

The problem are the second and third branch. I'm not sure how to set bound for the integral.

This is what I did:

$\int_1^2 x+c dx + \int_2^3c+4-xdx=1$, therefore $c=-1$. Is it correct?

Comment: Remarks: don't write $x = 1 \leq x \leq \ldots$. It's just $1 \leq x \leq 2.$

Comment: It is correct, $c=1$.